# How to install "speech recognition" module or another module on chaquopy in android

Tags: java, android, chaquopy

I'm trying to make an application that detects sound from the microphone and converts it to text.
I decided that the most suitable tool for this is chaquopy, because operations such as voice recognition and transcription are mostly done in python. Everything is ok but i can't install speech recognition library. Where could be the problem ? Can I download it in another way ?

**build.gradle(app)**

```
plugins {

    //for chaquopy(python)
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.talhakara.uzaktanegitimbitirmeprojesi"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       // for chaquopy(python)
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86"
        }
        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/enest/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38"

        }

        python{
            pip{
                install "speech-recognition-python"  
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }
        //
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}





dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'


    //implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.9.0') { transitive = true }


    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1"

   // implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
}
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        //chaquopy
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        //chaquopy
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:10.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Android gradle plugin version**
7.0.4

**Gradle version**
7.5-rc-1

**my python version**
3.8

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately speech-recognition-python requires pocketsphinx, which isn't currently supported by Chaquopy.

Comment: How can I solve this issue? is there anything else i can do?I s it only with pocketsphinx because I know there is a speech recognition library, can I not use it?

Comment: If you'd like to try building pocketsphinx yourself, you can use the Chaquopy package build tool. For details, see [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/175#issuecomment-778543307).